# forming difference equation

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

there is a square with $60$ equal blocks.

If a mosquito(bug)is set to fly starting at block $1$, it is equally likely to fly to other blocks. what is the probability after $n$ flies, the mosquito is at the $60\text{th}$ block (diagonally opposite to block $1$). form the difference equation.

I am trying to use law of probability to solve it but cannot form the equation.can anybody here can help. Thank you.

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me. Are *all* the other blocks equally likely? If so, let $p_n$ be the required probability. Then $p_n=(1-p_{n-1})\cdot\frac{1}{59}$.

Comment: Yes, all the blocks are equal in length and width.

Comment: The question was about the fly: must it fly only to a neighbouring block, or in one flight can it go anywhere? If only to neighbours, there is a problem. We cannot arrange $60$ squares into a square, so is it $3600$ squares?

Comment: ndre, thank you for your kind responses. It is a Single big square in which the the 60 square blocks are arranged in it. it is like a square with grids on it.after starting at the top left most block it is equally likely to fly to any of the blocks. the question is what is the probability that after n flies, it is on the bottom right most corner block of the square

Comment: Then I gave the recurrence in the first comment. It is linear, and relatively easy to solve.

Comment: Sir, very much appreciate your help. Also, if we say the bug starts flying from north east region of the whole big square, and  equally likely the bug will fly to other blocks, what will be probability after 'n' flies that the bug will be in the southwest region. will it be same difference equation. Appreciate again for your responses here

Answer (score 2):

We assume that the fly can be at any one of $60$ positions, and that in any flight, it chooses at random one of the $59$ other positions to go to.

Say it starts at position $A$. We want to find the probability that after $n$ flights it ends up at $B$, where $B$ is a *particular* position other than $A$.

Let this probability be $p_n$. We have $p_0=0$. The probability that after $n$ flights it ends up at $B$ is the probability it is at a position **other** than $B$ after $n-1$ flights, **and** goes to $B$ on the $n$-th. Thus
$$p_n=(1-p_{n-1})\cdot\frac{1}{59}.\tag{1}$$
There are various methods to solve linear recurrences. One way is to look first at the *homogeneous recurrence 
$$p_n=-\frac{p_{n-1}}{59},$$
which has the general solution $p_n=a\left(-\frac{1}{59}\right)^n$ for some constant $a$. Then we look for a *particular* solution of (1). Here we look for a constant solution $b$. So we want 
$b=(1-b)\cdot\frac{1}{59}$, which gives $b=\frac{1}{60}$. The general solution of the recurrence (1) is then 
$$p_n=a\left(-\frac{1}{59}\right)^n.$$
Choose $a$ to meet the initial condition $p_0=0$. We get $a=-\frac{1}{60}$, and therefore 
$$p_n=\frac{1}{60}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{59^n}\right).$$

**Remark:** There are many other approaches to the solution.

Comment: Sir, I am really stunned by your efforts here. So will equation 1 above will be the final difference equation or the last equation(after substituting a=1/60). Thanks again.

Comment: The last equation, just before the Remark, is the **final** equation for the probability. Equation (1) (no substitution, exactly as it is) is the difference equation. Of course it can be rewritten in various ways, such as $p_n=-\frac{1}{59}p_{n-1}+\frac{1}{59}$.

Comment: Thanks again sir. Is the initial condition P0= 1?. Can you kindly advise on that Sir.

Comment: The answer is in the answer: $p_0=0$. At time $0$ we are for sure at $A$, not at $B$.

Comment: You are welcome.